# Embedding html into webpage with c++

Tags: c++, google-chrome, firefox, embed

I was just wondering how far the possiblities stretch with c++ and what I can and cant do with it, I was just wondering if it would be possible for me to embed HTML code into every website I visit with C++. Do Firefox and Chrome have APIs for such things?

I know it's used in malware in the form of a 'web inject' does any one have any idea how they do it there?

Comment: Why do you mean by "embed HTML code into every website I visit"?

Comment: @sJuan76 The application would run on windows and everytime I visit any website an image would appear on all of them.

Comment: I know its possible to do with javascript, but I don't want to do it this way.

Answer (score 0):

The answer is yes but the way of doing it depends on what you really want to achieve.

If all you want is to embed some HTML into your Firefox browser, it might be possible to develop an [addon for Firefox](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/) [or a chrome extension](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/category/extensions).

Alternatively you could try and go about it the hard way and develop your own low level proxy which would do this for you (a lot of work).

C++ is very diverse and gives you many options so I recommend rephrasing the question to be more specific. For example, what you are asking is not necessarily to do with C++ itself but the browsers you mentioned (Firefox/Chrome). The modification you are after would be made to the browser so learn how to build Addons/Extensions for them.

Comment: The easiest way I thought about doing it would be to create a squid proxy and use c++ to change the proxy settings on windows and have the squid proxy embed HTML into each webpage. But I was just wondering if there was just a way to do it through pure C++ alone.

Comment: Yes there is but you will need to intercept the HTTP protocol (I'm not sure if you can do this for HTTPS easily), and you would need to then forward all requests on port 80 and process all downloads. Essentially you will be replicating what the browser is doing and then forwarding it to the browser itself.

Comment: You might as well download Firefox's code and modify it in that case. It's written in C++.